# what does operator<< in std namespace do?

Tags: c++

Of course following code works (it calls std::cout::operator<<):

```
cout << 1 << '1' << "1" << endl;
```

Happened to find there is also std::operator<<, and it seems it only works for char or char* arguments:

```
operator<<(cout, '1'); // ok
operator<<(cout, "1"); // ok
operator<<(cout, 1);   // error
```

So why do we need this operator and how to use it?

Thanks.

Comment: They're in § 27.7.3.1.

Comment: It would probably help to understand if you dissected the actual error message, particularly how the word "ambiguous" is used therein.

Comment: @izuriel the C++11 standard.

Comment: Just for reference, here is a digital copy of the standard: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf

Comment: @izuriel, And an older one at that. Use N3485 for C++11 :p

Comment: Which is where? That is the one I found.

Comment: @chris AFAIK the latest C++11 standard is not available online. One has to purchase the friggin' expensive printed version.

Comment: @izuriel, A quick search for N3485 landed me http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf.

Answer (score 7):

```
operator<<(cout, '1'); // ok
operator<<(cout, "1"); // ok
operator<<(cout, 1);   // error
```

The first two works because they invoke *non-member* functions taking two arguments. The functions which takes `char` and `char const*` as argument are defined as *non-member* (free) functions.

However, the function which takes `int` as argument is defined as *member* function, which means the third one needs to invoke a member function. If you invoke it as *non-member* function, then `int` would have to be converted into *some type* for which there exists a non-member function. So when this conversion is considered, it results in ambiguity because there are many possible conversions equally good.

As said, this should work:

```
cout.operator<<(1); //should work
```

As to why some functions are defined as members and others as non-members, I don't know the answer. It requires lots of study of the proposals and the decisions that led to this design of the library.

Comment: I think the confusion was more for why there is even a definition for `operater<<` in the `std` namespace more than why it was failing. But good info on why it was failing.

Comment: +1 and I concur with the analysis. I'm with the OP as well, however, in wondering why the free-operators were only supplied for char, signed char, and unsigned char, and pointers-to-said-same, but nothing else.

Comment: @WhozCraig Exactly. This seems like an inconsistency.

Comment: @WhozCraig I vaguely remember the early versions of the C++ operator system, where there weren't _any_ member operators. You still used `<<` back then. My point is that the reason might in fact be purely to do with historical accident…

Comment: @DonalFellows Likewise, I remember similar. 'twas a long time ago back when I was still in college and Turbo C++ had just been released (that dates me, egads) I poured over similar lib source.

Answer (score 0):

I always understood the reason for `char`, `unsigned char` and `char*` being defined as non-member functions *outside* the `basic_ostream` class is so it's easier to overload them.

See, all other `operator<<` use the `char` ones as building blocks. So if you want to create an `ostream` specialized to a specific `charT` character type and / or `traits` trait type - you only have to specialize these `operator<<` functions.

Had they been member functions, you'd have had to specialized the entire class (basically recreating all the class member functions).

I'm not sure that's the only reason, but that's how I've always seen it.